ArcGIS Pro CAD to Geodatabase returns no results
Despite successful convertion of CAD file to Geodatabase file in ArcGIS Pro I have nowehe results. They should appear in the panel as per this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8sbUMDbYVI&t=350s
but they don't
I've read about the problem with CAD files here:
https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/cad-gt-geodatabase-not-
and tried saving them in older versions. It didn't work either. Any hints?


The green bar would indicate that the tool ran successfully. What do the details say? What does the warning icon say next to Dataset name? If may have exported it but simply not added it to the map, go look in your CAD Project 6 gdb?

Does this answer your question? ArcGIS Pro doesn't see loaded DWG geodatabase

You need to use Catalog to navigate to the geodatabase you exported them to (CAD_Project_6.gdb in this case). Drag them onto the map from there.

I do so, but how about if the geodatabase is empty? I see the info like this or the box keeps closing down whenever the database is selected.
